# Автозагрузка классов с использованием use

Tags: php

Есть два файла:
A/A.php

```
namespace A;
function __autoload($class)
{
    $class = str_replaсe('\\', '/', $class);
    require_once "$class.php";
}
use C\B;
new B;
```

A/C/B.php

```
namespace A\C;
Class B{
}
```

Выдает ошибку "Fatal error: Class 'A\C\B' not found". Подсажите как исправить, уже все перепробовал.

Comment: Добавил автозагрузку

Comment: Странно, но Ваш код работает. Возможно Вы перепутали русскую `С` и английскую `C` :)